# OpenCV camera rvec tvec to ROS world pose

Tags: opencv, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm detecting Aruco tags using the OpenCV bridge and I have tvec and rvec returned with the tag pose related to the camera using OpenCV axis notations. I would like convert them to a ROS pose related to the camera frame, so I can visualize the tag pose in the world frame using RVIZ. What would be the best approach?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314828/opencv-camera-rvec-tvec-to-ros-world-pose/) by [veilkrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/39879/veilkrand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The frame of the pose openCV detects is already the camera frame, so you will just need to convert the tvec and rvec into a position and orientation repsectively.

The tvec is simply a translation vector so it's elements can be copied directly to the x, y & z values of the position in a pose message. Rvec is slightly more complicated however, you will need to use the openCV [Rodrigues](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga61585db663d9da06b68e70cfbf6a1eac) function to convert this into a 3x3 roation matrix. Then put the 9 values from the cv::Mat object into an equivalent [tf2:::Matrix3x3](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2/html/classtf2_1_1Matrix3x3.html) object. This object has a method getRotation which will return a quaternion of this rotation, now you have this quaternion you can copy its elements into the pose method.

Hope this makes sense.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [veilkrand](https://answers.ros.org/users/39879/veilkrand/) on 2019-02-06**:
What's the Python class to build a quaternion from a 3x3 rotation matrix?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`tvec` is a simple translation vector which can be used directly, `rvec` is a Rodrigues vector which first needs to be converted to a quaternion.

After I had to figure this out myself, here is some actual (Python) code based on PeteBlackerThe3rd's answer:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tf
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

rvec, tvec = cv2.some_function()

# we need a homogeneous matrix but OpenCV only gives us a 3x3 rotation matrix
rotation_matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 0],
                            [0, 0, 0, 1]],
                            dtype=float)
rotation_matrix[:3, :3], _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec)

# convert the matrix to a quaternion
quaternion = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_matrix(rotation_matrix)

# To visualize in rviz, you can, for example, publish a PoseStamped message:
pose = PoseStamped()
pose.header.frame_id = "camera_frame"
pose.pose.position.x = tvec[0]
pose.pose.position.y = tvec[1]
pose.pose.position.z = tvec[2]
pose.pose.orientation.x = quaternion[0]
pose.pose.orientation.y = quaternion[1]
pose.pose.orientation.z = quaternion[2]
pose.pose.orientation.w = quaternion[3]

pose_publisher.publish(pose)
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2020-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-03-13**:
I appreciate that you posted example code. Note that you can make the pose assignment shorter like this:

`pose.pose.position = geometry_msgs.msg.Point(*tvec)`
`pose.pose.orientation = geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion(*rvec)`

**Comment by [votecoffee](https://answers.ros.org/users/58616/votecoffee/) on 2021-05-14**:
I think you mean:

```
pose.pose.orientation = geometry_msgs.msg.Quaternion(*quaternion)
```

rvec is a 3x3 matrix

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2021-06-10**:
@votecoffee: Your comment regarding `quaternion` is correct, however, `rvec` is *not* a matrix but a rotation vector.  It is pointing along the axis of rotation and it's length gives the rotation angle around this axis.  It can be converted to a 3x3 rotation matrix with `cv2.Rodrigues` as shown above.

**Comment by [votecoffee](https://answers.ros.org/users/58616/votecoffee/) on 2021-06-10**:
Yes, you're correct.  rvec is a vector.  Thanks for the correction!